# How to solve $\ln(-2)=z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, complex-numbers, logarithms

$$\color{white}{\require{cancel}{.}}$$So I was looking through the Youtube homepage looking for math equations that I might be able to solve and I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX_23EWpF5U) video by blackpenredpen. The question was to find the value of $\ln(-2)=z$, which I thought that I might be able to solve.$$\text{Here is my attempt at solving }\ln(-2)=z\text{ :}$$$$\ln(-2)=z$$$$\iff\ln(-1\cdot2)=z$$$$\iff\ln(-1)+\ln(2)$$$$\text{I know that }a+bi\equiv re^{i\theta}$$$$\longrightarrow\text{ }-1=1\cdot e^{i\pi}$$$$\therefore\equiv\text{ }-1=e^{i\pi}$$$$\therefore\text{ }\ln(-1)+\ln(2)\implies\color{green}{i\pi}\cancel{\ln(e^{i\pi}})+\ln(2)$$$$\longrightarrow i\pi+\ln(2)=z\text{  (exact form)}$$$$\text{or }z\approx0.693147806+3.141592654i\text{ 
 (approximate form)}$$**My question**

---

Is my solution correct, or is there anything that I could do to attain the correct solution or attain it more easily?

**To clarify**

---

1. Sorry about the compressed formatting, it's just easier for me to write it out this way, if you want to uncompress it, then go ahead.
2. Sorry if this question is short/trivial.
3. Sorry if the tags are incorrect, they most likely are but okay.
4. Sorry if I used any math functions incorrectly.

Comment: Seems fine. I'll add that writing out in decimal form is generally not done unless the result is needed for some other future computation. It's clearer and more concise in its symbolic form.

Comment: @BrianTung Ah okay sorry I'll edit that out

Comment: No, I wouldn't say it's necessary to edit it out. I'm just making the point that we don't usually do it, but there are reasons to do it from time to time. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @BrianTung Oh okay that makes sense

Comment: I'll point out also that when dealing with logarithms of negative or complex numbers, we often distinguish the function $\log$ with the function $\text{Log}$ or $\ln$ with $\text{Ln}$, the capital letter versions giving a single result, the principal logarithm. The lowercase versions giving a family of results.  See [complex logarithm on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Principal_value).  It is like how people often get confused about $\sqrt{4}$ and saying that it is both $+2$ and $-2$, versus people saying that $\sqrt{4}$ gives only $+2$ as a result.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh okay that makes sense I'll try to remember that

Comment: The answer is correct. The question needs to specify in which field $z$ belongs to. In addition, the clarification section is not necessary since you are able to edit the post as needed.

Comment: To "attain more quickly" - splitting up $-2=-1\times2$ is not necessary.

Comment: @user170231 Oh okay

Comment: It's hard to follow your working due to the incoherent pepperings of `⟹` and `⟺`. They mean 'implies' and 'is equivalent to'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. The complex logarithm is motivated by the following iffy observation:

$$z=re^{i\theta}\iff \ln z=\ln r+i(\theta+2\pi k).$$ That is, assuming that the logarithm does work for complex numbers, the result is a multivalued function. Usually, the domain is restricted such that $k=0$, or

$$\ln z:=\ln|z|+i\arg z.$$ However, you can define it however you like. If you're like me, you leave the $2\pi k$ in there because I like to let the math tell me how it is, not the other way around.

Comment: So something like $\ln(1)+i\pi+2\pi k\text{ }\longrightarrow i\pi+2\pi k$?

Comment: @CrSb0001 Since $e^{2\pi i}=1$, $z=\ln(-2)$ is multiply defined. In other words, all points $z_k=\ln(2)+i\pi(2 k+1)$ satisfy $e^z=-2.$